# uncaught typeerror when using class getters on array elements

Tags: javascript, class, typeerror

In my js file I have a class *slideshow* and an array *slideshows* which I fill with instances of the slideshow class. Later in my code I use a for loop, where I iterate over each element in *slideshows* and try to get a specific value from it. However, when trying to run my code I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: slideshows[i].images[slideshows[i].shownImage] is undefined

My code looks like this:

```
let slideshows = [];

class slideshow{
    constructor(images){
        this._images = images;
        this._shownImage = 0;
    }

    get images() {return this._images;}
    get shownImage() {return this._shownImage;}

    set images(images) {this._images = images;}
    set shownImage(shownImage) {this._shownImage = shownImage;}
}

// This function is called when the page has loaded in
function setupSlideshow(){
    // Create Array of all slideshows
    slideshowDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div.slideshow");
    for(i = 0; i < slideshowDivs.length; i++){
        slideshows.push(new slideshow(slideshowDivs[i].querySelectorAll("slideshow-image")));
    }

    // Show Active Image
    for(i = 0; i < slideshows.length; i++){
        slideshows[i].images[slideshows[i].shownImage].style.display = 'block';
        // The line above this one triggers the error
    }
}
```

I believe the syntax isn't the problem, although I don't have a lot of experience with js classes. The only thing I can think of that could be the problem is that js doesn't know that slideshows[i] is of class slideshow and thus doesn't look at the functions I declared in my class.

Edits:

- added declaration of slideshows
- changed slideshowDivs += ... to slideshowDivs.push(...)

Comment: I don't see where you define or initialize the `slideshows` array. Also, images is not a property, but a function. So, you should try `slideshows[i].images()`.

Comment: _`slideshows +=`_  that's not how you add elements to an array. Use `slideshows.push()` instead

Comment: @Geshode slideshows is a global variable, I edited my code snippet to show that. Adding () doesn't seem to work, even the error code uses slideshows[i].images and not slideshows[i].images()

Comment: Sorry to repeat what you guys are saying in my answer; I was already writing it and didn't see the comments.

Comment: @Geshode `images` is a [getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). From the outside it looks like a regular property

Comment: _`"slideshow-image"`_  this isn't a valid selector. Is it meant to be a class? If so, it requires a `.` prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is on a different path than the one I was pursuing, hence the new answer.

It must be that there is no image at `slideshows[i].shownImage`. I would expect that this would cause an index out of bounds exception, not what you got, but can you see how if `slideshowDivs[i].querySelectorAll("slideshow-image")` returns nothing, then the slideshow will be created with no images, and therefore when you query an index in the images, it finds nothing? I think that's the problem.

Therefore, you should have a conditional statement, an if statement, that says

```
if (slideshowDivs[i].querySelectorAll("slideshow-image")) != null){
      slideshows.push(new slideshow(slideshowDivs[i].querySelectorAll("slideshow-image")));
}
```

Comment: This was the root of the problem, and Phil's comment showed what exactly was up: the argument I give to querySelectorAll is a class, yet I forgot to add a dot at the start. It thus returned null each time it was called. Adding the dot makes my code work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

`slideshows[i].shownImage` should be of type `int`, otherwise it can't be referenced as an index in `slideshows[i].images`. I'm not saying it's *not* an `int`, just make sure it is. AND: I know that you don't define types in JavaScript. But if you imply that it's a `String` or something, it can't act like a `String` and `int` both.

Second, `slideshows +=`... should be `slideshows.push(`... which implies that `slideshows` is an array and treats it accordingly.

Third, `slideshows` is never defined. You should say `var slideshows = []`. This is the root of it, I'd say, unless you defined it elsewhere in code not shown here. If you did define it elsewhere, then the problem would probably be that you didn't `push` to it as should be done for an array.

Edit: it is defined now, fixed by OP.
Edit: # 2 is fixed now.

Comment: I initialize shownImage as 0, clearly making it an int. it is then not touched until it is used as an index. If this is the problem, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: @RattatAndyGo: then I don't think that is the problem.